# How to dynamically create multiple graphs from an array VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an array of Variant/String Values as `SelectedTitles` and the way it works is that this can store columns. There will be two rows of the column with the name of column in one and units in the other. These can very in that the columns can be of 3000 to 9000 rows of data.

I found this code that is used to create plots based on columns that are already populated in a worksheet, but wouldnt it be faster to populate the plots prior using my array versus to actually printing the columns in a worksheet? Problem is i dont know how to cycle through columns stored in an array and graph them in their own plots. Also, is there a way to determine the increments of the x-axis? Say i wanted it to graph a y-value every 0.1 seconds? Thanks!!!

```
Sub AddCharts()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, ch As Shape, chartNo As Long
 Dim prevWith As Long, i As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet  'the sheet where the charts to be created
 'chartNo = 5
 chartNo = = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row - 1

 For i = 1 To chartNo
    Set ch = sh.Shapes.AddChart
    ch.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ch.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$" & i + 1 & ":$" & i + 1)
    ch.Chart.Parent.left = sh.Range("A1").left + prevWith 'here the first left chart position to be set
    prevWith = ch.Chart.Parent.width 'the chart width, the next one will be added to its right side
 Next i

 ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: There are many parameters that go into the specific graph you want, and as such, you may want to start recording a macro yourself while you create one, then tailor that.  Simply taking the code for a chart does not really provide much context as these are generally case-specific.  Also [see some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartarea(object)), noting you'll need to navigate in the left dock.

Comment: @Cyril so do you have a link by chance where i can learn to plot a chart with said parameters from an array?

Comment: I would think the [`SeriesCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.seriescollection) object within your chart is what you would like to work with, where you can set your `ChartName.SeriesCollection(1).Name`, `.Value`, and `.Xvalue`.